# Extracting innerHTML of Element from Web Page via CloudFlare Worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to extract the full innerHTML of particular element via a CloudFlare worker. I tried using their `HTMLRewriter` but that appears to be more of a stream API. It also doesn't appear to be able to return the full innerHTML content of an element.

Basically, I'm trying to create a CloudFlare worker that can go to this Stack Overflow page and extract all the HTML inside the first `<div>`. Does anybody know how I can do this?

I also tried importing Cheerio from a CDN but was unable to figure out how to get that working as well.

Comment: See https://github.com/adamschwartz/web.scraper.workers.dev

Answer (score 0):

Try Fast HTML Parser to get HTML DOM tree in cloudflare workers.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34659064)